# Arduino - What is [./n.]?

Tags: arduino

I was making a dimmer in arduino using a potentiometer and I found a website that told me to convert the Analog values (0-1023) to Voltage (0-255). The line that converted simply divided 255 by 1023 and multiplied it with the potentiometer reading. The line for this was `ledWrite = (255./1023.) * potRead;`. I tried to write is as `ledWrite = (255/1023) * potRead;`, with the periods, but the code wouldn't run.

What's `./n.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment

```
ledWrite = (255./1023.) * potRead;
```

is equivalent to

```
ledWrite = (255.0 / 1023.0) * potRead;
```

That is, the trailing *zero* **can be omitted**.

On the *Arduino Uno*, the constants are interpreted as **doubles** and the result of the division is a *double* value.

[At the present time](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Double), note that a *double* and a *float* have the same precision (*4 bytes*) on most *Arduino* boards, with the exception of the *Arduino Due*.

---

In the following line

```
ledWrite = (255/1023) * potRead;
```

the two numeric *literals* are interpreted as **integers** and the division operation is the one among *integers*, which in this case always returns *0* since *255* is smaller than *|1023|*.